# Can ZFC commit cardinality errors?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Add a primitive a one place function symbol $c$ to represent "True cardinality" of a set, to the first order language of set theory.

Add the following axiom schema:

**1. Cardinal Equality:** If $\phi(x,y)$ is a formula in which *both and only* $x,y$ occur free, and only occur free, then all closures of:

$\forall X,Y: \\\forall x \in X \exists! y \in Y (\phi(x,y)) \land  \\\forall y \in Y \exists! x \in X (\phi(x,y)) \\ \to c(X)=c(Y)$

are axioms.

Add the following $\omega$-rule of inference:

**2. Cardinal Inequality:** If $\psi(X); \varphi(Y)$, are formulas in which $X,Y$ occur free and only free respectively, then:

From: $\big{[}$if $\phi(x,y)$ is a formula in which *both and only* $x,y$ occur free, and they only occur free, then all closures of the following formula are true:

$\forall X,Y (\psi(X) \land \varphi(Y) \to \\\neg [\forall x \in X \exists! y \in Y (\phi(x,y)) \land  \\\forall y \in Y \exists! x \in X (\phi(x,y))]) \big{]}$

______________________we Infer

All closures of $\forall X,Y (\psi(X) \land \varphi(Y) \to c(X)\neq c(Y) )$ are true.

Now if a set theory T extended with the above, proves that:

$\exists X,Y: |X|\neq|Y| \land c(X)=c(Y)$

Then its guilty of committing cardinaity error of the first kind.

If it proves that:

$\exists X,Y: |X| = |Y| \land c(X) \neq c(Y)$

Then its guilty of committing cardinality error of the second kind.

Now NFU is an example of a set theory that commit cardinality error of the first kind, but this cannot occur in ZFC.

> Can ZFC commit cardinality error of the second kind?

Based on comments with Monroe Eskew. The following question presents itself.

> Is there a natural statement that the theory "ZFC + ZFC doesn't commit cardinality error of the second kind" can settle, that ZFC + V=L cannot?

**NOTE:** The axiom schema and the $\omega$-inference rule had been edited, the prior version didn't require $x,y$ to be the sole free variables in $\phi(x,y)$ and that older version was answered by Greg Kirmayer towards ZFC proving that it cannot commit error of second kind, but it did this via a parameter. The more restrictive version present above is meant to enforce a restrictive principle on ZFC, and the second question is about such a restriction.

**After note** if we are testing whether a theory T is committing a cardinality error, then only primitives of theory T are allowed in the cardinal equality schema and the cardinal inequality inference rule, i.e. $c$ cannot be used.

Comment: It sounds like you’re asking if it is consistent with ZFC for two sets to be in bijection, without there existing a definable bijection.  Do I read that right?  If so, please ask your questions in this more straightforward way.  Anyway, the answer can be found by looking at a model with a countable set of reals that is not definable.  For example, add omega many Cohen reals.  See Jech’s book.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, yes this is part of it, but I'm not really sure if it burns down to that only. For example if I add the axiom that ZFC do not commit cardinality error of second type, would that enforce all sets in ZFC to be definable?

Comment: It would require that whenever sets are in bijection, then there is a definable bijection.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, can there be a definable bijection between the set of all reals and some ordinal, i.e. can there be a definable well ordering on the reals? would stipulating ZFC not committing cardinality error of second kind, be inconsistent?

Comment: It is consistent. It holds in the minimal model.

Comment: @do you mean a model of ZFC + V=L?

Comment: Yes but more specifically, the least $L_\alpha$ satisfying ZFC. One can prove that every set is definable without parameters in that model.

Comment: @MonroeEskew would you consider that model to be the standard model of ZFC?

Comment: It's a rather unusual one.  I mostly like big ones.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, from those comments I'm realizing that ZFC + ZFC doesn't commit cardinality errors. To be an even more restrictive condition than ZFC + V=L. Are there natural mathematically looking statements that this theory can settle and that ZFC + V=L cannot?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is uncountable and $L_\alpha$ satisfies ZFC, then it will have non-definable reals, and thus countable sets without a definable bijection with $\omega$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, I meant statements similar in kind to the continuum hypothesis, I mean naturally looking statements that ZFC + V=L cannot settle, but "ZFC + No cardinality error is committed" can answer. Are there examples of such statements, since the latter theory is more minimal than the former.

Comment: I am changing the answer to the modified questions because it is wrong.

Comment: OK, I've removed the 'answered' status on the question, so that you can edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume |X| is the least von Neuman ordinal for which there is a bijection from it to X. Then ZFC cannot "commit cardinality error of the second kind". This is true because your axiom scheme and 
rule of inference hold in ZFC  when c(X) is |X|.

In order to verify the rule of inference holds when c(X) is |X|, suppose ()∧() and |X|=|Y|. Then there is a bijection f between X and Y. Let (,,z) be the formula (xy)∈z. Then (∀∈∃!∈((,,f))∧∀∈∃!∈((,,f).

Please note that the statement "Now NFU is an example of a set theory that commit cardinality error of the first kind, but this cannot occur in ZFC." is misleading because usually |X| has a different meaning 
in ZF then in NF.

I deleted my last comment because it was not correct, and am adding the answers to the modified(parameters not allowed) questions. 
If ZF is consistent, then the answer to the first modified questions is no. If ZF is consistent so is ZF+V=L. The modified axioms and rules of inference hold in ZF+V=L when c(X) is interpreted as |X|.
Let < be a definable well ordering of the universe. In order to verify the rule of inference holds when c(X) is |X|, suppose ()∧() and |X|=|Y|. Let b be the least cardinal such that there exist
s and t for which (s)∧(t) and |s|=|t|=b. Let x be <-least such that (x) and |x|=b. Let y be <-least such that (y) and |y|=b. Let f be the <-least bijection from x to y. Let (s,t) be a formula 
which holds when and only when f(s)=t. Then (∀s∈x∃!t∈y((s,t))∧∀t∈y∃!s∈x((s,t).
If ZF is consistent then the answer to the second modified question is yes because "ZFC doesn't commit cardinality error of the second kind" implies Con(ZF).

Comment: correction of previous comment:Suppose |X|=|Y|. Then there is a bijection f from X to Y. Let (,,z) be the formula (xy)∈z. Then ∀∈∃!∈((,.f))∧∀∈∃!∈((,.f). Thus c(X)=c(Y). Suppose there are X and Y with c(X)=c(Y) and |X|≠|Y|. Let b be the least cardinal of such an X. Let () be the formula |X|=b. Let () be the formula |Y|≠b. By the inference rule c(X)≠c(Y) whenever () and (). This contradicts our choice of b and thus c(X)=c(Y) iff |X|=|Y

Comment: what if we forbid $\phi(x,y)$ from having parameters?

Comment: I didn't get your comment regarding the second c(X)=c(Y) and |X| $\neq$|Y|. are you suggesting that b=c(X) and also that b=|X|, why should those agree, there might be no set X assigned the same cardinal object value under both $c$ and || functions? and why the inference rule should result in c(X)$\neq$c(Y)

Comment: @what is the proof that there is a model of that theory in which c(X)=|X|? by the way I don't think the global choice function is a definable function, so how you'll introduce it in your argument?

Comment: formulas must not use the symbol "c" because it is not a primitive of the tested theory.

Comment: notice that the question is "can" and not "does", it might be the case that ZFC doesn't commit cardinality errors but it "can" commit them, it means it doesn't prove that it doesn't commit them. I tend to think that it is provable in this extended theory that ZFC cannot commit cardinality error of the first kind, but definitely it can commit the second kind error, and that's why Monroe Eskew was speaking about in his comments.

Comment: This proves that ZFC would not prove the existence of sets which possess cardinailty errors yes, but it doesn't say that ZFC is inconsistent with them. I think that ZFC is inconsistent with errors of the second kind, but some models of ZFC can commit errors of the first kind, so the theory "ZFC + ZFC commits error of the first kind", is I think consistent. Actually even some models of ZFC+V=L can commit cardinality error of the first kind

Comment: your formulation include "c", which must not be used in formulations of axioms and inference rules, because they are not primitives of the tested theory. I didn't mention that right. But it should be like that.

Comment: The question poser wrote  "I didn't get your comment regarding the second c(X)=c(Y) and |X|≠|Y|". This is a proof that |X|=|Y| iff c(X)=c(Y), in the given extension of ZFC(with parameters).
First we showed that if |X|=|Y|, then c(X)=c(Y). Then we assumed that c(X)=c(Y) and |X|≠|Y| and obtained a contradiction. b is the least cardinal such that there exist X and Y with |X|=b and c(X)=c(Y) and |X|≠|Y|. The conditions of the rule are met by this choice of  and . The conclusion of the rule yields a contradiction and so our assumption could not have held.

Comment: The question poser wrote "notice that the question is "can" and not "does", it might be the case that ZFC doesn't commit cardinality errors but it "can" commit them".
"if a set theory T extended with the above, proves that:∃,:||≠||∧()=()
Then its guilty of committing cardinaity error of the first kind." Perhaps this needs to be changed.

Comment: No! It doesn't need to be changed, the definition is clearly saying "committing" also "guilty" of, it doesn't say "..then it can commit cardinality error...", 'can' mean that some models of the theory can suffer this cardinality error, which I think the majority of models of ZFC does commit cardinality error of the second kind, but never of the first kind.

Comment: "if a set theory T extended with the above, proves" a certain statement, then it is "guilty of committing cardinaity error of the" first(or(with different statement) second) kind. What it means for a 
model for the language with a binary relation symbol, or a model for the language with a binary relation symbol and a function symbol, to suffer a cardinality error has not been defined.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that a model M of the language with a binary relation ∈ and a functon symbol c commits a cardinality error of the first kind if ZFC holds in M for the ∈-formulas, the Cardinal Equality axioms hold in M, the Cardinal Inequality rules hold in M, and ∃,:||≠||∧()=() holds in M.  Also maybe you mean that a model M for the language with a binary relation symbol ∈ does not commit a cardinality error of the first kind if for all functions f:M-->M, (M,f) does not commit a cardinality error of the first kind.

Comment: Yes it is the first option (with "c" not allowed to be used in the formulation of cardinal in equality and cardinal equality), you forgot that ZFC has identity relation also = with the first order identity axioms.

Answer (score 6):

This principle as written isn't appropriate for the class of theories including NF and NFU.  If the formula $\phi$ is restricted to be stratified and have $x$ and $y$ of the same relative type then the principle is true in NF and so in any of its fragments (this is the real answer).

In NF, the universe is a set, the set of all singletons is a set, and there can be no bijection between them.  Suppose there were such a bijection f from singletons onto sets.  Then we could define
the set $R = \{x : \lnot (x \,E\, f(\{x\}))\}$ (this definition would be stratified).  Now consider $f^{-1}(R) = \{r\}$, $r \,E\, R \iff \lnot \ r \,E \,R$ follows.

There are fragments of NF in which this argument does not work:  these inevitably have seriously impaired comprehension principles and are very weak.  I believe that in versions of NF with predicativity restrictions on comprehension, one can arrange for all infinite sets to be the same size.  But mathematically these systems are quite weak, and the principle Zuhair suggests becomes true in a trivial sense.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Professor Holmes!

Comment: Welcome Professor Holmes!

Comment: NFU: This time it's MUTUAL.

Comment: In reality the principle is posed in a general manner over "any" first order theory T. So it has nothing to do with the particulars of NFU or ZFC or any other theory, and its not intended for use in a specific theory. The principle capture the intuitive idea of cardinality errors that runs against existence definable bijections at class level (first kind error), or that pose bijections for which no definable witness is there (second kind error).

Comment: You need to change your answer about the power of fragments of NF that can escape this argument since clearly SF + Infinity + choice + every object has |V| many co-extensional copies do clearly violate your argument and yet it is as strong as NFU + infinity + choice. So your argument about inevitable weakness of fragments of NFU escaping that argument is not correct.